# Variable initialized inside do{} is not incrementing

Tags: java, scope, initialization

Just for practice I was trying to run the following code in two different scenario initially I thought both of them would work but when i ran the program one works and one not, here is the code which work

```
public class Test1
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {

    int counter = 0; 
    int number = 1;
    do{ 
        System.out.println(number);
        number++; 
        counter++; 
    }while(counter<20);
}  }
```

O/P : 1 2 3 ... {Gets print up to 19}

Here is the one which didn't worked

```
 public class Test2
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int counter = 0; 
    do{ 
        int data = 0; 
        System.out.println(data);
        data++; 
        counter++; 
    }while(counter<20);
}  }
```

O/P : 0 0 0 0 ...{Gets print up to 19 times }

Comment: Well yes, you're initializing `data` to `0` at the start of each iteration of the loop. It's not clear why you'd *expect* that to print anything else. Each iteration effectively has a separate `data` variable. If you don't want that, declare and initialize it outside the loop as per your first piece of code...

Comment: @JonSkeet got it i know i shouldn't i was just trying but didn't think that through !!

Answer (score 4):

Because inside every iteration, your data field will be set to 0 first then you are printing it and then ++ it

```
public class Test2
    {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
        int counter = 0; 
        do{ 
           int data = 0; // declare a new data field and initialize to 0
           System.out.println(data); // display zero
           data++; // data now is 1
           counter++; 
        }while(counter<20);
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The output is correct, Because the data `variable` is initialized to `0`in every iteration.

```
 public class Test2
    {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
        int counter = 0; 
        do{ 
            int data = 0; System.out.println(data); data++; counter++; 
        }while(counter<20);
    }  }
```

Consider the do .. while loop

Assume the first iteration

```
1.int data = 0; // data will be 0 
2.System.out.println(data); // prints 0
3.data++;//Incrementing the data to 1
4.counter ++;// incrementing the counter to 1
```

Second iteration

```
1.int data = 0; // data will be again set to  0 
2.System.out.println(data); // prints 0
3.data++;//Incrementing the data to 1
4.counter ++;// incrementing the counter to 2
```

So the output will be data 0,0,0......... and counter will be 1,2,.....

> The scope of the data will be local and reinitialized every time , TO avoid the problem you should make the variable out of the loop like you done in first code sample